# creating reproducible example using reprex package in r where a local file is being read

Tags: r, tidyverse, reproducible-research, reprex

I often use `reprex::reprex` to create reproducible examples of `R` code to get help from others to get rid of errors in my code. Usually, I create minimal examples using datasets like `iris` or `mtcars` and it works well. 
But I always fail to use `reprex` any time I need to use my **own** data since the problem is so specific and I can't rely on datasets from `datasets` library.

In that case, I get the following error:

```r
# loading needed libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(devtools)

# reading the datafile
data <- utils::read.csv(file = "data.csv")
#> Warning in file(file, "rt"): cannot open file 'data.csv': No such file or
#> directory
#> Error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection
```

Created on 2018-02-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

There is a great discussion from pre-`reprex` era elsewhere ([How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)). The author recommends using something like `dput`-

> If you have some data that would be too difficult to construct using
>   these tips, then you can always make a subset of your original data,
>   using eg `head()`, `subset()` or the indices. Then use eg. `dput()` to
>   give us something that can be put in `R` immediately

But also mentions-

> If your data frame has a factor with many levels, the `dput` output
>   can be unwieldy because it will still list all the possible factor
>   levels even if they aren't present in the subset of your data.

So, if I want to work will my full dataset, this is not a good option.

In summary:

Anyone knows how to create a `reprex` which is standalone even if it relies on using a local file containing **all** of your data?

Comment: The error says there's no such file in your working directory. You need to change your working directory to point to where the file is located.

Comment: Reduce the problem to a **minimal** reproducible example. Get it down to a size that makes sense to `dput`. Rarely does an example require all your data. StackOverflow doesn't allow you to upload data files so your problem should be self contained. If you absolutely need a particular full data file, post it publicly to the internet and use the URL to point people to it, eg `read.csv("http://www.myspecial.com/data.txt")`

Comment: That error persists even if my working directory contains that file.

Comment: Uploading your file to a site like [ShareCSV](http://www.sharecsv.com/) would be easier like MrFlick suggested

Comment: If your data is less than 25MB you can even post it to Github and `read.csv("http://raw.githubusercontent.com/rest/of/url/to/your/data")` straight into the R session. But definitely follow @MrFlick 's guidelines above too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, reprex strongly encourages execution in the session temp directory. But sometimes it is unavoidable to refer to a specific local file, so yes, there has to be a way to do this.

To request that all work be done in *current working directory*, set `outfile = NA`. (More generally, you can use the `outfile` argument to specify a base file name and path.)

If I submit this reprex, with working directory set to my home directory:

```r
reprex({
  getwd()
  writeLines(c("V1,V2","a,b"), "precious_data.csv")
  list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
  read.csv("precious_data.csv")
  },
  outfile = NA,
  venue = "so"
)
```

I get this output:

```r
getwd()
#> [1] "/Users/jenny"
writeLines(c("V1,V2","a,b"), "precious_data.csv")
list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
#> [1] "precious_data.csv"
read.csv("precious_data.csv")
#>   V1 V2
#> 1  a  b
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Using `outfile = NA` or `outfile = "path/to/desired/file/base"` is the general pattern for asserting control over the location of all files generated by `reprex()`.