# How do i turn this into a reprex

Tags: r, reprex

Struggling turning this into a reprex due to the local csv file it uses. 
It says the file is not found in the directory. Any help is great thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(cronR)
library(miniUI)
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(pdftools)
library(tm)
library(readtext)
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)
library(openxlsx)
library(rio)
library(reprex)


RAO <- readr::read_csv(file = "RateAddOnsExcel.csv")
RAO <- as.data.frame(read.csv(file = "RateAddOnsExcel.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ","))
RAO$X10.01.18 <- NULL
RAO$...4 <- NULL
RAO$...5 <- NULL
RAO$Quarter. <- NULL
names(RAO)[1:13] = c("ProviderName","AIMNumber", "ChainName", "RateEffectiveDate", "ComponentTotal", 
                     "VentAddOn", "QualityAddOn", "SpecialCareUnitAddOn", "AssessmentAddOn", 
                     "SelectedExpenditureAddOn", "RateReduction", "CaseMixRate", "CaseMixAssessment")
RAO[grepl("Myers", RAO$ProviderName),]
RAO[!grepl("Index", RAO$ProviderName),]

View(RAO)
reprex::reprex(outfile = NA)
```

Comment: Well is the file really in the good directory? ``getwd()``. Have you try to do it with the full path to the file? Also why do you ``read_csv()`` the file 2 times?

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem of "How to make a reproducible example involving a local CSV file?" or "How do I solve this 'file not found' error?". Normally, I'd assume you want to fix the error, but since your title is "*How do i turn this into a reprex*", I want to doublecheck.

Comment: @Gregor Good question, I assumed he wanted to solve 'file not found' so he could then use it as a reproducible example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating reproducible example using reprex package in r where a local file is being read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874304/creating-reproducible-example-using-reprex-package-in-r-where-a-local-file-is-be)

Comment: @Gregor I was wanting to know hot to get rid of the error to turn it into a reprex